# what meant by openGL ES implementation on OS

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I'm started looking for docs for OpenGL ES learning, I came across lot of links. one of them has explained like "OpenGL need to be supported by the vendors of Graphics Cards (like NVidia) and be implemented by the OS's vendors (like Apple in his MacOS and iOS) and finally, the OpenGL give to us, developers, a unified API to work with".

what does it mean by?

> OpenGL need to be supported by the vendors of Graphics Cards (like NVidia)

Is it something different to normal code libraries execution?

> be implemented by the OS's vendors (like Apple in his MacOS and iOS)...

Is this OS's vendor specific?

If all implementation was done by vendors, what does actually OpenGL ES will do?

I was thinking OpenGLES is a library, which needs to install in required OS and using the specific EGL API's, we need to call them? isn't it?

> finally the OpenGL give to us, developers, a unified API to work with

If Os itself developing everything, why to go for OpenGL ES?

Please explain, possibly with an example.

Comment: Doesn't your description itself answer your question? "_OpenGL gives a unified API to developers_"

Answer (score 0):

Unlike his name suggests, OpenGL is **not** a library. Or better, it is cause some symbols for the functions you use need to be linked to the executable.

But OpenGL is a *standard de facto* library, and a great part of the OSes have a good part of the implementation in their kernel. OSX and iOS provide the OpenGL.framework and GLKit.framework to interface with OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Architecture Review Board ARB just gives specification of OpenGL. This means It tells what should be name of function which parameters it should accept and what is desired behavior.  All the Graphics card vendors take this specification and implement this api. Here function interface and high level working is defined by ARB but internal implementation of API is done depending upon the hardware of vendor. Now this OpenGL API goes into driver. Drivers are generally implemented as Operating system interface part and hardware interface part. So Operating system also need some support for this driver.